# Why isn't the todo being deleted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working through a tutorial for a course I'm taking. The lab I'm working on walks through creating a to-do app. I'm on step 3, which asks us to create a button that deletes a task. I feel ridiculous, because I know I can figure it out but...well, I haven't yet! I will post the code to see if there are any initial issues, and then update with the methods I've already tried. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const newTodo = {
          id: new Date().getTime(),
          text: todo.trim(),
          completed: false,
      };

      if (newTodo.text.length > 0) {

          setTodos([...todos].concat(newTodo));
          setTodo("");

      } else {

          alert("Enter Valid Task");
          setTodo("");
      }
  }

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
      let updatedTodos = [...todos].filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
      setTodos(updatedTodos);
  }

  const button = <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>

return (
    <div>
        <h1>To-do List</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Add a new task"
                    value={todo}
                />
                <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
            </form>
            {todos.map((todo) => <div>ID: {todo.id} Task: {todo.text} {button}</div>)}
    </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I didn't just copy and paste, so it's possible that I messed something up while typing. I'm expecting the deleteTodo() function to accept a todo.id and filter the list of todos, excluding the one I want to delete. I'm thinking that the issue may be cause by the way I've created the button? Again, I'm not sure why I can't figure it out. TIA.

EDIT: Okay, it works now! Thank you all so much for explaining this. For anyone else that comes across this problem, here's where I mis-stepped:

```js
const button = <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}Delete<button>
```

@Nicholas Tower's explanation was very clear--creating this outside of `.map(...)`causes deleteTodo to get the todo *state*, not the not the todo I want it to delete from the `todos` array. @Lars Vonk, @0stone0, and @Sudip Shrestha all said this as well. @Sudip Shrestha and @pilchard also helped correct the deleteTodo function. Again, I really appreciate all the help. The code works now. I'll show the updates so people having a similar issue can compare:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const newTodo = {
          id: new Date().getTime(),
          text: todo.trim(),
          completed: false,
      };

      if (newTodo.text.length > 0) {

          setTodos(todos.concat(newTodo));
          setTodo("");

      } else {

        alert("Enter a valid task");
        setTodo("");
      }
  }

  // update the state using setState, rathar than mutating it directly @Sudip Shrestha
  const deleteTodo = id => {
      setTodos(prevState => {
          return prevState.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)
      });
  };

// line 51: button placed inside .map(), as per many suggestions below.
return (
    <>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Add a new task..."
                    value={todo}
                />
            </form>
            {todos.map((todo) => 
                <div>
                    ID: {todo.id} Task: {todo.text}
                    <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>)}
    </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: no need to spread your `todos` arrays in either of your methods as both `concat()` and `filter()` don't act on the original arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const button = <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
```

You're creating this button element just once, and the `todo` variable it refers to is the todo state, which is a string (usually an empty string). Since `todo` is a string, `todo.id` is `undefined`, and `deleteTodo` can't do anything with that.

You need to create separate buttons for each item, so you should move this code down into your `.map`:

```
{todos.map((todo) => (
  <div>
    ID: {todo.id} Task: {todo.text}
    <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
  </div>
))}
```

Now each item has its own button, with its own onClick function. And in those functions, `todo` is the item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The button cannot access which todo it has I think you should put the code from the `const button` where you are referring to it or by changing it to `const button = (todo) => <button onClick={ () => deleteTodo(todo.id); }>Delete</button>` and access it by doing `{button()}`

Comment: I understand now, thank you! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
const button = <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
```

This has the same callBack for each todo, you should move this inside your `map` so that `todo.id` refers to the iterator of the `map()`:

```
{todos.map((todo) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>ID: {todo.id} Task: {todo.text}</div>
        <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
    </React.Fragment>
))}
```

---

Updated Demo:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const newTodo = {
          id: new Date().getTime(),
          text: todo.trim(),
          completed: false,
      };

      if (newTodo.text.length > 0) {

          setTodos([...todos].concat(newTodo));
          setTodo("");

      } else {

          alert("Enter Valid Task");
          setTodo("");
      }
  }

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
      let updatedTodos = [...todos].filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
      setTodos(updatedTodos);
  }


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>To-do List</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Add a new task"
                        value={todo}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
                </form>
                {todos.map((todo) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div>ID: {todo.id} Task: {todo.text}</div>
                        <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const button = (t) => <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(t.id)}>Delete</button>
```

and then, in the map

```
{todos.map((todo) => <div>ID: {todo.id} Task: {todo.text} {button(todo)}</div>)}
```

this way, the "delete todo" button will be bound to the specific todo ID, avoiding being bound to whatever the current value of `todo` is in the app.

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution! This makes more sense than what I tried to do. I don't know why I missed this idea!

Answer (score 0):

1. Its better to update the state using ***setState***. Muting the state directly breaks the primary principle of React's data flow (which is made to be unidirectional), making your app very fragile and basically ignoring the whole component lifecycle.
2. Also You need to change the ***delete*** from string to function and pass the id or place the jsx directly inside map function.

```js
 import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const newTodo = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      text: todo.trim(),
      completed: false,
    }

    if (newTodo.text.length > 0) {
      setTodos([...todos].concat(newTodo))
      setTodo('')
    } else {
      alert('Enter Valid Task')
      setTodo('')
    }
  }

   /*
   * Changed Here
   */
  const deleteTodo = id => {
  
    setTodos(prevState => {
      return prevState.filter(todo => todo?.id != id)
    })
  }

  const button = id => <button onClick={() => 
  deleteTodo(id)}>Delete</button>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>To-do List</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={e => setTodo(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Add a new task"
          value={todo}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
      </form>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <div key={todo.id}>
          ID: {todo.id} Task: {todo.text} {button(todo.id)}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in:

```
const button = <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
```

You can use

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`btn ${props.className}`}
      title={`${props.title}`}
      onClick={props.onClick ? () => props.onClick() : null}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

after that, call it like this

```
<Button className="delete" title="delete" onClick={()=>deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</Button>
```

Comment: I didn't think about doing it this way! Thank you!